# Sum key value pairs of identical keys in nested Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following array of hashes -

```
array = [{:Air_Duct_Cleaning=>{:impressions=>92, :clicks=>2, :conversions=>0}, :Carpet_Cleaning=>{:impressions=>297, :clicks=>0, :conversions=>0}, :Brand_Terms=>{:impressions=>273, :clicks=>9, :conversions=>1}}, {:Brand_Terms=>{:impressions=>275, :clicks=>3, :conversions=>0}}, {:Air_Duct_Cleaning=>{:impressions=>51, :clicks=>1, :conversions=>0}, :Carpet_Cleaning=>{:impressions=>225, :clicks=>0, :conversions=>0}, :Brand_Terms=>{:impressions=>326, :clicks=>12, :conversions=>2}}]
```

I'm attempting to sum the key value pairs of identical keys.  For example -

```
air_duct = array.map {|m| m[:Air_Duct_Cleaning]}.compact
=> [{:impressions=>92, :clicks=>2, :conversions=>0}, {:impressions=>51, :clicks=>1, :conversions=>0}]

air_duct_total = air_duct.inject{|x,y| x.merge(y){|a,b,c| b + c}}
=> {:impressions=>143, :clicks=>3, :conversions=>0}
```

However, I need to do this without knowing the keys of the first level hash (won't know the key of `:Air_Duct_Cleaning`).  I was trying to iterate through the array running something like

```
key_groups = array.map {|m| m.map {|key, value| key}}
```

Hoping that would position each key in place of `:Air_Duct_Cleaning` and I'd get something like

```
[{:Air_Duct_Cleaning =>{:impressions=>92, :clicks=>2, :conversions=>0}, {:impressions=>51, :clicks=>1, :conversions=>0}, {:Carpet_Cleaning => {:impressions=>297, :clicks=>0, :conversions=>0}, {:impressions=>225, :clicks=>0, :conversions=>0}, {:Brand_Terms => {:impressions=>273, :clicks=>9, :conversions=>1}, {:impressions=>275, :clicks=>3, :conversions=>0}, {:impressions=>326, :clicks=>12, :conversions=>2}]
```

So I could then use something like

```
totals = key_groups.map {|m| m.inject{|x,y| x.merge(y){|a,b,c| b + c}}}
```

And ultimately end up with

```
[{:Air_Duct_Cleaning => {:impressions=>143, :clicks=>3, :conversions=>0}, {:Carpet_Cleaning => {:impressions=>522, :clicks=>0, :conversions=>0}, {:Brand_Terms => {:impressions=>874, :clicks=>24, :conversions=>3}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will yield the desired output, without using explicit keys of the input Array:

```
array = [
  { Air_Duct_Cleaning: { impressions: 92, clicks: 2, conversions: 0 }, Carpet_Cleaning: { impressions: 297, clicks: 0, conversions: 0 }, Brand_Terms: { impressions: 273, clicks: 9, conversions: 1 }},
  { Brand_Terms: { impressions: 275, clicks: 3, conversions: 0 }},
  { Air_Duct_Cleaning: { impressions: 51, clicks: 1, conversions: 0 }, Carpet_Cleaning: { impressions: 225, clicks: 0, conversions: 0 }, Brand_Terms: { impressions: 326, clicks: 12, conversions: 2 }},
]

result = array.reduce({}) do |o, hash|
  o.merge(hash) { |_, v1, v2| v1.merge(v2) { |_, vv1, vv2| vv1 + vv2 } }
end

p result
# {
#   :Air_Duct_Cleaning=>{:impressions=>143, :clicks=>3, :conversions=>0}, 
#   :Carpet_Cleaning=>{:impressions=>522, :clicks=>0, :conversions=>0}, 
#   :Brand_Terms=>{:impressions=>874, :clicks=>24, :conversions=>3}
# }
```